# Legendre–Fenchel transformation $ f^{\ast}(x^\ast)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\{\langle x,x^\ast\rangle -f(x)\} $

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

The convex conjugate also known as Legendre–Fenchel transformation of a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ is definite by 
$$
f^{\ast}(x^\ast)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\{\langle x,x^\ast\rangle -f(x)\}
$$

> **Question**. Are there any books or other reference (other than Wikpedia, wolfram or PlanetMath or similar) dedicated solely to a exhaustive approach to  convex conjugation ?

On the approach I mean both a theoretical treatment of the properties of the convex conjugation as methods of calculation for the convex conjugation explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

- An introduction to the subject, in the context of Banach spaces, can be found at the end of the first chapter (section $1.4$) of the book

  H. Brézis, *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differentrial Equations*
- A quite thorough exposition of the subject in $\Bbb R^n$, with a number of applications to convex analysis and optimisation methods, can be found in the book

  J.-B. Hiriart-Urruty, C. Lemaréchal, *Convex Analysis and Minimization Algorithms II*

  Starting from chapter $X$ (it continues in subsequent chapters). The book is in two volumes, and volume *II* contains several references to volume *I*.